double commutant of unitary operators of a Von Neumann algebra.
Let $M$ be a Von Neumann algebra. I am having trouble showing that the double commutant of unitary operators for $M$ is equal to $M$. I have shown it with projections using borel functioncal calculus. At first I thought using mean ergodic theorem, but ran into issues since this uses a specific type of projection i.e. $\{x \in H: Ux = x\}$ when I am trying to pick any projection in $M$. I was thinking of trying to show that the projections of $M$ is a subset of the double commutant of the unitary operators of $M$.
I don't think I completely understand borel functional calculus. Given borel subset $S$ of the spectrum of some normal element, then $E(\chi_S)$ is a projection where $E$ is the unique projection valued measure on the borel sets of the spectrum. Is there a way we can determine the closed subspace for the projection from this?

If $\def\U{\mathcal U}\U$ denotes the set of unitary elements in $M$, to show that $\U''=M$ what you do is to notice that $\operatorname{span}\U=M$. This is easy to prove: if $a\in M$ is selfadjoint and $\|a\|\leq1$, then
$$
a=\frac12\,\big[a+i(1-a^2)^{1/2}\big]+\frac12\,\big[a-i(1-a^2)^{1/2}\big]
$$
is a linear combination of two unitaries. For arbitrary $x\in M$, write $x=a+ib$ with $a,b$ selfadjoint, and then
$$
x=\|a\|\,\frac{a}{\|a\|}+i\|b\|\,\frac{b}{\|b\|}
$$
is a linear combination of four unitaries. It follows that $U'=M'$.
As for your second question, you shouldn't expect to be able to explicitly characterize the spectral projections, save for some very special cases.

Let $q=\chi_{\{0\}}(x)$, $p=\chi_{\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\}}(x)$. Then
$$\tag1
p+q=1,\qquad qx=0,\qquad px=x. 
$$
Let also $r$ be the projection onto $\ker x$ and $s$ the projection onto the closure of the range of $x$. Because $x$ is normal, we have
$$\tag2
r+s=1,\qquad xr=0,\qquad sx=x.
$$
From $px=x$ we get that $ps=s$, so $s\leq p$. Then $r=1-s\geq1-p=q$.
Let $\xi\in\ker x$. From $x\xi=0$ we get that $f(x)\xi=0$ for all $f\in C(\sigma(x))$ such that $f(0)=0$. Then $f(x)\xi=0$ for all Borel $f$ such that $f(0)=0$. In particular, $p\xi=0$. This means that $q\xi=\xi$, which in turn tells us that $r\leq q$. Then $r=q$ and $s=p$. That is, $\def\ran{\operatorname{ran}}$
$$
\chi_{\{0\}}(x)=[\ker x],\qquad \chi_{\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\}}(x)=[\ran x].
$$

Thanks this proof makes complete sense. I read somewhere that $\chi_{\sigma(x) \setminus {0}}(x) = P_{(\ker x)^\perp}$ where $x$ is normal and $\sigma(x)$ is the spectrum of $x$. I haven't gone through the complete proofs of borel functional calculus, but I am unsure why(if) it is true.

I have edited some detail in.

Giving a concrete expression for $E(S)$ for arbitrary Borel sets $S$ is a bit too ambitious, but I would say the situation is not quite as hopeless as Martin's answer suggests.
First note that if $x$ is normal, then $x=y+iz$ with commuting self-adjoint elements $y,z$, namely $y=\frac 1 2(x+x^\ast)$, $z=\frac 1{2i}(x-x^\ast)$. The spectral measure $E_x$ of $x$ is the product of the spectral measures $E_y$ of $y$ and $E_z$ of $z$ in the sense that
$$
E_x(S\times T)=E_x(S)E_y(T)
$$
for $S,T\subset\mathbb R$ Borel.
For $x$ self-adjoint there is an explicit description of $E(S)$ at least if $S\subset \mathbb R$ is a compact interval. More precisely, let $S=[a,b]$ and $c=\frac 1 2(a+b)$ the midpoint of $I$. Then $E(S)$ is the projection onto
$$
H_S=\{\xi\in H: \lVert (x-c1)^k\xi\rVert\leq (b-c)^k\lVert\xi\rVert\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb N\}.
$$
This can be seen by the spectral theorem: If $\xi\in E(S)H$, then
\begin{align*}
\lVert (x-c1)^k\xi\rVert^2&=\lVert (x-c1)^k\chi_S(x)\xi\rVert^2\\
&=\int_{[a,b]}(\lambda-c)^{2k}\,d\langle\xi,E(\lambda)\xi\rangle\\
&\leq (b-c)^{2k}\int_{\mathbb R}d\langle\xi,E(\lambda)\xi\rangle\\
&=(b-c)^{2k}\lVert\xi\rVert^2.
\end{align*}
Conversely, assume that $\xi\notin E(S)H$. Since $\mathbb R\setminus[a,b]=\bigcup_{\epsilon>0}(-\infty,a-\epsilon]\cup[b+\epsilon,\infty)$, we have $(1-E(S))\xi=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(E((-\infty,a-\epsilon])\xi+E([b+\epsilon,\infty))\xi)$. In particular, we can assume without loss of generality that $E([b+\epsilon,\infty))\xi\neq 0$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\lVert (x-c1)^k\xi\rVert^2&\geq \int_{[b+\epsilon,\infty)}(\lambda-c)^{2k}\,d\langle\xi,E(\lambda)\xi\rangle\\
&\geq (b+\epsilon-c)^{2k}\int_{[b+\epsilon,\infty)}\,d\langle\xi,E(\lambda)\xi\rangle\\
&=(b+\epsilon-c)^{2k}\lVert E([b+\epsilon,\infty))\xi\rVert^2,
\end{align*}
which implies that $\xi\notin H_S$.
Then you can also describe the spectral projections onto unbounded closed intervals and open intervals as limits using the continuity properties of the spectral measure. For example, since $\{0\}=\bigcap_{\epsilon> 0}[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, the spectral projection $E(\{0\})$ is the projection onto
$$
\bigcap_{\epsilon> 0}H_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}=\{\xi\in H:\lVert x^k\xi\rVert\leq \epsilon^k\lVert \xi\rVert\text{ for all }\epsilon> 0,\,k\in\mathbb N\}=\ker x.
$$
Therefore $E(\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\})$ is the spectral projection onto $(\ker x)^\perp$ (recall that the spectral measure is supported on $\sigma(x)$).
Edit: The last part is correct, and I'll leave it here as illustration of the limiting procedure, but of course it's much simpler in this case: $\{0\}=[-0,0]$ and $E(\{0\})=H_{\{0\}}=\ker x$.
